# how can I change month only in java date object?

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I have java date object.

How can I change its month without changing the year.

e.g.

12/1/14

I want to change it to

12/3/14 and to 12/10/14

I basically want to change the month by +/- x month without changing the year.

Can it be done?

Comment: Start by not using `Date`. Bizarrely enough given the name, a `Date` isn't a date - it's just an instant in time, which could be on different dates depending on which time zone (and calendar system) you view it in.

Comment: Be aware that Java offers *two* `Date` classes, both [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system): `java.util.Date` & `java.sql.Date`. The first represents a moment as seen in UTC, while the second *pretends* to represent only a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone, while actually having both time & zone. Both of these classes are terribly flawed in design, and should be avoided. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes, `Instant` and `LocalDate` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date); // your date (java.util.Date)
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, x); // You can -/+ x months here to go back in history or move forward.
return cal.getTime(); // New date
```

ref : [Java Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: No, the add-method can overflow to next year or previous year. But the OP wants to preserve the year. An alternative might be the roll()-method, but the set()-method is probably the best way.

Comment: Update: The `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaSqlDate      // Object of terrible legacy class `java.sql.Date` that *pretends* to represent a date-only value.
.toLocalDate()     // Convert to modern replacement, `java.time.LocalDate`. 
.withMonth( 3 )    // Swap out month for March while keeping the year and day-of-month.
```

… or:

```
myJavaUtilDate                      // Object of terrible legacy class `java.util.Date` representing a moment as seen in UTC.
.toInstant()                        // Convert to modern replacement, `java.time.Instant`. 
.withZone(                          // Adjust from UTC (offset of zero) to a specific time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )     // Real time zone names have format of `Continent/Region`. 
)                                   // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalDate()                      // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.plusMonths( 2 )                    // Add two months while trying to keep same day-of-month. Returns another `LocalDate` object rather than altering the first, per immutable objects pattern.
```

## java.time

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of ( 2017, Month.JANUARY, 23 );
LocalDate localDateFeb = localDate.withMonth ( 2 );
```

…or…

```
LocalDate localDateFeb = localDate.withMonth ( Month.FEBRUARY.getValue ( ) );
```

> localDate.toString(): 2017-01-23

> localDateFeb.toString(): 2017-02-23

The other Answers use the troublesome old date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

### Adapt from `java.sql.Date` class

If you have a `java.sql.Date` class in hand, convert from that terrible legacy class to its modern replacement, `java.time.LocalDate`. Call the new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
LocalDate localDate = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate later = localDate.plusMonths( 2 ) ;  // or `withMonth( 3 )`.
```

### Adapt from `java.util.Date` class

If you have a `java.util.Date` class in hand, convert from that terrible legacy class to its modern replacement, `java.time.LocalDate`. To get there, we must jump through a couple hoops.

A `java.util.Date` object represents a moment, not a date, despite the class name. By "moment" I mean a date with time-of-day as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. So we need to convert from this legacy class to its modern replacement, `java.time.Instant`. Call the new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to the old classes.

```java
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

#### Zone determines date

You want a date. But there is a [speed-bump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_bump) here. Understand that for any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. At a given moment, it may be "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously still "yesterday" in Toledo Ohio US. So perceiving a date for a given moment requires a time zone.

For a time zone, use class `ZoneId`. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply that time zone to adjust from UTC of an `Instant`. The adjustment results in a `ZonedDateTime`. Both the original `Instant` and the `ZonedDateTime` represent the very same moment, the same point on the timeline, only their wall-clock time is different.

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

From that moment (date with time-of-day) as seen in that particular time zone, we want only the date for your work. So extract a `LocalDate` object. And add or swap your for your desired month.

```java
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate later = ld.withMonth( 3 ) ;  // Or `.plusMonths( 2 ) `.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

Update: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library has a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class to represent a date-only without a time-of-day nor time zone.

You can arbitrarily set the month value. But beware of the issue that not all months have the same number of days, so having day-of-month values of 29, 30, and 31 are a problem.

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2014 , 12 , 31 ); // December.
LocalDate localDate_Feb = localDate.withMonthOfYear( 2 ); // February.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );
System.out.println( "localDate_Feb: " + localDate_Feb );
```

When run.

```
localDate: 2014-12-31
localDate_Feb: 2014-02-28
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [set method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)) of the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)) class to change the specific month you want

**sample:**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getTime());
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY); //will change the month to JANUARY
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

**result:**

```
Sun Aug 17 03:17:35 EDT 2014
Fri Jan 17 03:17:35 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the month using the set method.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //prints the current date    
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.July); //changes the month to july    
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // prints the edited date
```